# Deploying GWT app to Glassfish 3.0

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, deployment, gwt, glassfish-3

I'm having some troubles figuring out if its possible to run a GWT Application inside a Glassfish Application Server 3.0.

I was already able to run it using Tomcat, but that seemed more natural and more easy to do.

Can you point out a place where I can learn how to deploy my app to glassfish?

I'm currently using GWT Plugin with Eclipse 3.6, I also added the Glassfish Server Plugin, thinking that would help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having some troubles figuring out if its possible to run a GWT Application inside a Glassfish Application Server 3.0.

It should be possible to run a GWT project on any WTP server using the Google Plugin for Eclipse.

> Can you point out a place where I can learn how to deploy my app to glassfish?

Try the [following instructions](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/f318b979bc13e2ee?pli=1) to get WTP and GPE working together.

Comment: @vrmpx: BTW, feel free to mark the answer as accepted (the green tick below the vote counter on the left) if you think this answer deserves it :)